# Is it possible to have a multiple build but a single test runner on GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a runner setup for my project (iOS) and I have multiple build phases which can happen concurrently, but I can only run a single test at a time. I want to limit this test phase to 1 for all pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one runner (A) for the build stage and one runner for the test stage (B). Runner A would have limit of N jobs run simultaneously while Runner B would have the limit of 1.

See the [documentation](https://gitlab.com/wiget/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md) for more info on the runners' configuration.

Comment: Thanks - seems like the only way to do it currently.